# Bullets become super fast as the angle gets closer 90

Tags: java, swing, game-physics, angle, java-threads

so I'm developing a game in Java and I'm trying to shoot bullets towards the cursor position- the shooting part is OK but as the angle between the cursor and the player (the player shoots the bullets so essentially its the bullet's first coordinates) get closer to 90 (or -90) the bullets going super fast and I have no idea why

[The red zone is the super-speed zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZGik.jpg)

Code:

```
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        final double currentY=y;
        final double currentX=x;

        double slope = (cursorPos.y - currentY) / (cursorPos.x - currentX);
        double angle= Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(cursorPos.y - currentY, cursorPos.x - currentX));
        System.out.println(angle);
        while (true){
            try {
                double newY;// y = m * (x-x.) + y.
                newY = ((slope*(x - currentX))+currentY);
                y= (int) newY;
                if ((angle <=-90 && angle>=-180) || (angle >=90 && angle<=180) )
                {
                    x--;
                }
                else {
                    x++;
                }
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The way your trajectory is created: one point is calculated for every step value of `x`; and is always takes the same time (`Thread.sleep(5)`) between one point to the next. So, the speed will depend on the distance between one point and the next. According to Pythagoras' theorem, that distance is `sqrt(1 + (newY - y)**2)`. If the trajectory is mostly horizontal, `(newY - y)` is small, so the bullet travels a small distance during `Thread.sleep(5)`. If the trajectory is mostly vertical, then `(newY - y)` is large, so the bullet travels a large distance during `Thread.sleep(5)`.

Comment: In order to get a constant speed, you need to either renormalize the time, or renormalize the distance between a point and the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stepping x in time by fixed increments of one.  So when the bullet lines are near vertical, the slope m is a big number, and they're covering m pixels per step in y.  The closer to vertical, the faster they go.

Instead you need to step in fixed increments of distance along the line segment the bullet is following.  If the endpoints are (x0,y0) and (x1,y1), then varying t from 0 to 1 in the equations x = t*(x1-x0)+x0;  and y=t*(y1-y0)+y0 will sweep the line segment. To sweep by units of 1 pixel, you need to know how many pixels there are along the line. That's L = sqrt(sqr(x1-x0) + sqr(y1-y0)), so the values of t are i / L for i = 0 to L.

You'll need to do these computations with floating point numbers.

Another note is that you'll probably eventually have trouble using Sleep as you are. This prevents the Swing event handling loop from doing any work while it's waiting.

Comment: So i need to "put" the thread inside a for loop and update t accordingly and the x increments will be x+=t? (Not really sure I got that right)

Comment: One way is to use a Java Timer. Here's a Conway's game of life that shows how that can work. https://gist.github.com/gene-ressler/99c4a8ca13fa07b5eea6

Comment: So the timer can help me solve the sleep problem, but I dont think its going to solve the super speed issue

Comment: The answer above explains the solution to the super speed problem exactly. Just re-do the math. You can worry about Sleep later.

Comment: Problem fixed! 
thanks :)

btw L should be `sqrt(pow(x1-x0,2) + pow(y1-y0,2))` :)

Comment: No. I used sqr() intentionally. You should define a little function that returns x*x. pow() is much more expensive than a simple multiply. In this little application it won't make a significant difference. But best to form good habits from the start.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks :)